# How to find out programmatically if a sequelize model attribute's is a foreign key and to what model does it refer to

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to make a dynamic update  function for my application that does two things,

-checks if the new values are different from the old ones to avoid updating and thus changing the updated_at timestamp for no reason if no value is actually being changed

-checks if one of the attributes the user wants to change is a foreign key, and then checks if the said user modification refers to an actual row from the referred to model or not in order to avoid getting the error

so I need a way to extract information about attributes from the model the dynamically, and more precisely I need to be able to check if an attribute is a foreign key, and if it is I need to find the name of the model it is referring to

Comment: Regarding foreign keys, it seems like you are trying to write code that is already implemented in the DBMS.  That's a lot of work!   IMHO your effort would be better spent writing code to handle the foreign key error (i.e. notify the user, etc).  (I do like your other idea, looking for actual changes)

Comment: Well in case of the foreign key error, there is not enough data, meaning it dosn't mention the fieldName encountring the problem, so you can accurately tell the use where the problem resides, and for the unique values, it only gives you the first unique field with a problem and not all of them, which isn't ideal either as it is needed in case of forms for example, in order to give the user accurate feedback, i managed to do what i needed after much trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone needs this, here is how i managed to do it :

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Unique keys checks

const hasUniqueConflicts = async (model, parameters)=>{

  const uniqueFields = getUniqueFields(model, Object.keys(parameters))
  const returns = new Set()
  const uniqueParameters = uniqueFields.map(field=>{return {[field]:parameters[field]}})
  // Check if any of the values of the unique fields already exists
  const results = await model.findAll({where:{[Op.or]:uniqueParameters}})

  if(results.length){
    for(result of results){
      for (field of uniqueFields){
        if(parameters[field] === result[field]) returns.add(field)
      }
    }
    return Array.from(returns)
  }

  return false
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Foreign keys checks

const hasForeignKeyProblems = async (model, parameters)=>{
  const foreignKeys = getForeignKeys(model, Object.keys(parameters))
  const returns = new Set()

  for(field of foreignKeys){
    const valid = referencedRowExists(model, field, parameters[field])
    if (!valid) returns.add(field)
  }

  if (returns.size) return Array.from(returns)
  return false
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const referencedRowExists = async (model, foreignKey, foreignKeyValue)=>{
  if(foreignKeyValue === null && isNullable(model, foreignKey)) return true

  const models = getModels(model)
  const tableName = getReferencedTableName(model, foreignKey)
  for (table in models){
      if (models[table].tableName == tableName){
          referenceExists = await rowExists(models[table], foreignKeyValue)
          if (referenceExists) return true
          break
      }
  }
  return false
}

const isNullable = (model, fieldName) => model.rawAttributes[fieldName].allowNull

const IsUnique = (model, fieldName) => model.rawAttributes[fieldName].unique

const IsForeignKey = (model, fieldName) => model.rawAttributes[fieldName].references && true

const getModels = (model) => model.sequelize.models

const getUniqueFields = (model, fieldNames) => fieldNames.filter(field=>IsUnique(model, field))

const getForeignKeys = (model, fieldNames) => fieldNames.filter(field=>IsForeignKey(model, field))

const getReferencedTableName = (model, foreignKey) => model.rawAttributes[foreignKey].references.model

const rowExists = async (model, parameter) => Object.keys(parameter).length ? !!(await model.count({where: parameter})) : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out... looks like you can just use a hook for the first part on all your models... https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8762. And i agree with Ken on the part above, your database will already prevent you from doing that so trap that error and customize what you wanna send back, instead of adding a bunch of preventative code.. Obviously you have some way to identify what model is the intended target of your input so you shouldn't need to worry about accessing attribute data.

Comment: I managed to do what i needed done, but sequelize errors aren't good enough for my use case, here are some examples :

- Case 1: you have user registration, the user enters both an already used username and already used email, you juste try to create the user and catch sequelize error, the error only has information about one of the fields, so you can't accurately give all he feedback needed by your users

Comment: - Case 2: you have a model with multiple foreign keys, your user somehow manages to send a request with 1 of the foreign keys pointing to a reference that does not exist, how can you accurately tell the user where he messed up whem sequelize constraint error dosn't mention the field name with the problem

Comment: I don't like hacking stuff around the way i did either, but i don't see how else i can give complete and accurate feedback

Comment: when you say sequelize error, do you mean the error postgres is throwing back?

Comment: I mean the error i catch from sequelize when there is a problem (in developement environment i'm using sqlite as of now), but i don't know if things are different with mysql or postgres

Comment: out of curiosity, did you try setting unique error messages for all your fields in your model?  Maybe it will only tell you the first problem it finds though.. i have not tried that myself passing in multiple fields that would fail

Comment: yes it definitely gives feedback about the first problem only, and about setting messages, i haven't tried it yet as i didn't need it, i'm building an api, and i have a custom error objects and a customerror handler  that only needs a code and an object to know what the exact problem is and to send back it to the user without any critical information leaking